# Trying to open a file from Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a question about opening a file in a jupyter notebook. The file I'm trying to open is in a different directory than where the jupyter installed.  I am trying to open that file path then print the file.

The words in the file to make sure it opened the file.
my code is this:

```py
path = B:\\RogueSquadron\\python\\testFile.txt
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for word in f
    print(word)
```

and my error message is this

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-be6f6ef99f23>", line 1
    path = B:\\RogueSquadron\\python\\testFile.txt
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thanks for you help!

Comment: `path = ...` --> `path = "..."`

Comment: Comment: Thankyou, predicated by those who helped..../

Comment: newest comment. In jupyter, and modelling NLTK part of speech. using tag, only finding a few VB but no V 2036,00 words and also smaller 7 word sample

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "B:\\RogueSquadron\\python\\testFile.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for word in f:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
path = r"B:\RogueSquadron\python\testFile.txt"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for word in f.read().split():
        print(word)
```